# 'using' is an invalid keyword argument for this function (serializer.save(using='tableNew'))

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

Im trying to save a record in a table (here the selection of table is dynamic). I'm able to pull the records from the respected table's dynamically. where as while saving the data ended with an error {'using' is an invalid keyword argument for this function}

below is the code.

Views.py

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)


def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(using='users_1')
```

And my Serializer.py contains

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Users
          fields = ('id','firstname', 'lastname', 'mobile_number')

      def create(self, validated_data):
          return Users.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Where is the code that succesfully gets the data dynamically? `using` is for querysets, and refers to databases, not tables.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, This way i was able to fetch the results from a table dynamically
return Users.objects.using('user_1').all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing the method `save` of the serializer and the method `save` of the Django model. And `using`is not setting the table, but the database.

I think you want to pass `using` to Django's model `save`.

**If you want to change the database:** (for table see below)

To pass the `using` table to the model's `save` method, you need to add ["extra context" to your ViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) via `get_serializer_context()`. It should return a dictionary. In your case

```
[...]

get_serializer_context(self)
    return {'using': 'users_1'}
```

As next what you also need to do is to override the `create()` methods of your Model Serializer.

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   [...]
   def create(self, validated_data):
      obj = JobSeekers(**validated_data)
      obj.save(using=self.context['using'])
```

**Specifying the table** :

For specifying a particular table it is usually an argument of the Model.Meta:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users_1'
```

If you want to set the *table* dynamically and not the *database* I think you can create a Model and for each table a specific [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). Then select your proxy model dynamically from code.

Edit: if Proxy Model will not work, you can try with [`abstract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

NOTE: Everything here is untested and written from memory but I it is a good starting point.

Comment: thank you @user3142459, i tried it. But now i'm receiving a new error like 'Column 'company_id' cannot be null'. Infact there is no such a column in my table.

Comment: have you applied migrations?

Comment: my table having foreign key relation, changed accordingly. Its working. Thanks @user3142459